# dask_sql is throwing error when "order by" is used inside sql queries

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I am using dask_sql to run a sql query. Here is what I have written:-

```py
from dask_sql import Context

c=Context()
c.create_table("dftable", df) #df is a dask dataframe, which is already present 

result= c.sql("""select * from dftable order by claim_id""")
```

Here, error arises and below is the error:-

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeArray' object has no attribute 'tobytes'

ERROR:dask.dataframe.shuffle:ignoring exception to ensure_cleanup_on_exception
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "C...........
```

But, when I remove "order by" from sql query then everything runs fine.

```py
result=c.sql("""select * from dftable""") #It runs fine
```

Comment: This being so specific, I suggest you raise an issue on the github repo for dask-sql.